# How to - Gitlab custom environment variables to be exported to a .env file before build

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab project with custom environment variables defined in the UI. Now, before the build step in my pipeline - I want to place a .env at the root of the project with "ALL" the custom variables exported to the file. I understand I can do single exports using echo $var_name >> .env or something but Really need to do all of them at once (only custom defined)

```
  stage: Creating Artifacts
  cache: 
    key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-$CI_PROJECT_DIR
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - env >> ".env" #HERE IS THE PROBLEM - IT EXPORTS ALL DEFAULTS INSTEAD OF CUSTOM VARS
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    name: 'staging_api'
    untracked: false
    expire_in: 30 days
    paths: 
    - ./dist
    - ./node_modules
    - .env
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to work .env with npm.

Try to use `env >> ".env"` instead `env > ".env"`. It will override full .env file by current environment variables.
if you have in .env specific default values, I suggest define default variables in .gitlab-ci.yml. The default variables was overridden by UI variables.